# Hide subcategories (widget)

Tags: php, categories, widgets

So I have a widget which has the option to hide categories from it. The list with options to hide consist of both categories and subcategories. Now, the problem is, if I tick any parent category then all subcategories of that category will automatically be shown also. Meaning nothing will be hidden if the parent category is selected. If I only tick subcategories without its parent, well then nothing will be shown as its parent isn't ticked. 
Any ideas on how I can hide certain subcategories while showing its parent category of course? Clearly, something is wrong in the code.

The widget PHP:

```
    <?php 

function MyTheme_get_custom_taxonomy_count($ptype,$pterm) {
    global $wpdb;

    $s = "select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."terms where slug='$pterm'";
    $r = $wpdb->get_results($s);
    $r = $r[0];

    $term_id = $r->term_id;



    //--------

    $s = "select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."term_taxonomy where term_id='$term_id'";
    $r = $wpdb->get_results($s);
    $r = $r[0];

    $term_taxonomy_id = $r->term_taxonomy_id;


    //--------

    $s = "select distinct posts.ID from ".$wpdb->prefix."term_relationships rel, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta, $wpdb->posts posts 
     where rel.term_taxonomy_id='$term_taxonomy_id' AND rel.object_id = wpostmeta.post_id AND posts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id AND posts.post_status = 'publish' AND posts.post_type = 'project' AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'closed' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '0'";
    $r = $wpdb->get_results($s);



    return count($r);
}


add_action('widgets_init', 'register_browse_by_location_widget');
function register_browse_by_location_widget() {
    register_widget('MyTheme_browse_by_location');
}

class MyTheme_browse_by_location extends WP_Widget {

    function MyTheme_browse_by_location() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'browse-by-location', 'description' => 'Show all locations and browse by location' );
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 200, 'height' => 250, 'id_base' => 'browse-by-location' );
        $this->WP_Widget( 'browse-by-location', 'MyTheme - Browse by Location', $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
        extract($args);

        echo $before_widget;

        if ($instance['title']) echo $before_title . apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']) . $after_title;

        $loc_per_row    = $instance['loc_per_row'];
        $widget_id      = $args['widget_id'];
        $nr_rows        = $instance['nr_rows'];
        $only_these     = $instance['only_these'];
        $only_parents   = $instance['only_parents'];

        if($only_parents == "on") $only_parents = true;
        else $only_parents = false;


        $nr = 4;

        if(!empty($loc_per_row)) $nr = $loc_per_row;
        echo '<style>#'.$widget_id.' #location-stuff li>ul { width: '.(round(100/$nr)-0.5).'%}</style>';

        if($nr_rows > 0) $jk = "&number=".($nr_rows * $loc_per_row);

        $terms_k = get_terms("project_location","parent=0&hide_empty=0");
        $terms = get_terms("project_location","parent=0&hide_empty=0".$jk);


        //$term = get_term( $term_id, $taxonomy ); 

        if($only_these == "1")
        {
            $terms = array();

            foreach($terms_k as $trm)
            {
                if($instance['term_' . $trm->term_id] == $trm->term_id)
                    array_push($terms, $trm);
            }

        }


        //-----------------------------

         if(count($terms) < count($terms_k)) $disp_btn = 1;
        else $disp_btn = 0;


        $count = count($terms); $i = 0;
        if ( $count > 0 ){
             echo "<ul id='location-stuff'>";
             foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

               if($i%$nr == 0) echo "<li>";
               $total_ads = 0;
               $terms2 = '';
                $terms2 = get_terms("project_location","parent=".$term->term_id."&hide_empty=0");

                $mese = '';

                    $mese .= '<ul>';
                    $mese .= "<img src=\"".get_bloginfo('template_url')."/images/location.png\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\" /> 
                    <h3><a href='".get_term_link($term->slug,"project_location")."'>" . $term->name;

                    //."</a></h3>";

               $total_ads = MyTheme_get_custom_taxonomy_count2('project', $term->slug, 'project_location'); //MyTheme_get_custom_taxonomy_count('project',$term->slug);

               $mese2 = '';
               if($terms2 && $only_parents == false)
                {

                    foreach ( $terms2 as $term2 ) 
                    {
                        $tt = MyTheme_get_custom_taxonomy_count2('project', $term2->slug, 'project_location'); //MyTheme_get_custom_taxonomy_count('project',$term2->slug);
                        //$total_ads += $tt;
                        $mese2 .= "<li><a href='".get_term_link($term2->slug,"project_location")."'>" . $term2->name." (".$tt.")</a></li>";
                    }
                }

                    echo $mese."(".$total_ads.")</a></h3>";
                    echo $mese2;

                    echo '</ul>';


               if(($i+1) % $nr == 0) echo "</li>";

               $i++;

             }

                //if(($i+1) % $nr != 0) echo "</li>";


             echo "</ul>";

         }           

        if($disp_btn == 1)
        {
                echo '<br/><b><a href="'.get_permalink(get_option('MyTheme_all_locations_page_id')).'">'.__('See More Locations','MyTheme').'</a></b>';     
        }       



        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {

        return $new_instance;
    }

    function form($instance) { ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title'); ?>:</label>
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" 
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['title'] ); ?>" style="width:95%;" />
        </p>

         <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('only_parents'); ?>"><?php _e('Only show parent categories'); ?>:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('only_parents'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('only_parents'); ?>" 
            <?php echo (esc_attr( $instance['only_parents'] ) == "on" ? "checked='checked'" : ""); ?> />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('loc_per_row'); ?>"><?php _e('Number of Columns'); ?>:</label>
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('loc_per_row'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('loc_per_row'); ?>" 
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['loc_per_row'] ); ?>" style="width:20%;" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('nr_rows'); ?>"><?php _e('Number of Rows'); ?>:</label>
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('nr_rows'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('nr_rows'); ?>" 
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['nr_rows'] ); ?>" style="width:20%;" />
        </p>


         <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('nr_rows'); ?>"><?php _e('Only show locations below'); ?>:</label>
            <?php echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$this->get_field_name('only_these').'"  value="1" '.(
     $instance['only_these'] == "1" ? ' checked="checked" ' : "" ).' /> '; ?>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('nr_rows'); ?>"><?php _e('Locations to show'); ?>:</label>

                <div style=" width:220px;
    height:180px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    overflow:auto;border:1px solid #ccc">
     <?php

     $terms = get_terms("project_location","project_location=0&hide_empty=0");
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$this->get_field_name('term_'.$term->term_id).'"  value="'.$term->term_id.'" '.(
     $instance['term_'.$term->term_id] == $term->term_id ? ' checked="checked" ' : "" ).' /> ';
     echo $term->name.'<br/>';

     }

     ?>

    </div> 



        </p>


    <?php 
    }
}




?>
```

Anything looking wrong there? Or is it category.php that needs some adjustments?

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Anyone?

I don't know if it is "easier" to set it to "Hide selected items" or "Show selected items" ?
Perhaps the first is easier to code, so: exclude the selected items?